# $\frac{1}{\log_2(x-2)^2}+\frac{1}{\log_2(x+2)^2}=\frac{5}{12} $ Find all x's

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> It is given that $$\frac{1}{\log_2(x-2)^2}+\frac{1}{\log_2(x+2)^2}=\frac{5}{12} $$ Find all possible values of $x$.

**What I did:** $$\frac{1}{\log_2(x-2)}+\frac{1}{\log_2(x+2)}=\frac{5}{6} $$ $$\log_{(x-2)}2 +\log_{(x+2)}2 =\frac{5}{6}$$

What is the next ? I stuck in here..

**I am looking for algebraic approach. The answer is $+6,-6$**

Comment: @Laplacian for another record : try $-6$ . I am looking for algebraic solution , i have answer key

Comment: @Laplacian be careful ,  what is $(-6-2)^2$ ? .Look at the original question , not my try

Comment: For the term with $x-2$ you can only do what you did if $x-2>0$, so $x>2$. For $x<2$, the log simplifies to $2\log_2({2-x})$ Similar for the second term.

Comment: Didn't find an algebraic way, but I can prove it by analysis.

Comment: Don't know why my comments vanished... Anyway I said: one solution for the record is $+6$.

Comment: @Laplacian no , you said the **only** solution for the record is $+6$. Do no lie.. everyone can make mistake , do not shame

Comment: @doritos Yes, and then you said to look at the original question.

Comment: @MathFail i am looking for algebraic way

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = \log_2(x-2)$ and $b = \log_2(x+2)$.  Then your equation becomes:

$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{5}{6}$$
$$\frac{a + b}{ab} = \frac{5}{6}$$
$$6(a + b) = 5ab$$
$$b = \frac{6a}{5a - 6}$$
$$\log_2 (2^a + 4) = \frac{6a}{5a - 6}$$

This has the integer solution $a = 2$.  Unfortunately, while this solution is easy to *verify*, it's hard to see how to explicitly solve for $a$.

Anyhow, with $\log_2(x-2) = 2$, we get $x - 2 = 4$, or $x = 6$.

Comment: But using that approach how can we get $x = -6$?

Comment: @ItsTrex: That solution disappears in OP's earlier step of converting $\log y^2$ to $2 \log y$.

Answer (score 0):

Ah you meant $\log_2((x-2)^2)$ not $(\log_2(x-2))^2$? That wasn't clear to me. Are you sure that its +- 6? [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Flog%5E2_2%28x-2%29%20%2B%201%2Flog%5E2_2%28x%2B2%29%20%3D%205%2F6) gives completely different answers, no matter whether I use $\log_2((x-2)^2)$ or $(\log_2(x-2))^2$.

This might help you a bit, but don't expect really nice answers unless you've made a mistake in the phrasing of your question.
$$\frac{1}{\log_2((x-2)^2)} + \frac{1}{\log_2((x+2)^2)} = \frac{5}{12}$$

$$\frac{1}{2\log_2(x-2)} + \frac{1}{2\log_2(x+2)} = \frac{5}{12}$$

$$\frac{1}{\log_2(x-2)} + \frac{1}{\log_2(x+2)} = \frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{\log_2(6 - 2)} + \frac{1}{\log_2(6 + 2)} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6}$ so clearly 6 is an answer.

Comment: It's a basic common notation that $\log^2(\cdot) = (\log(\cdot))^2$, whereas $\log(\cdot)^2 = \log(\cdot^2)$

Comment: You have the wrong number on the right-hand side.  Correct that and WA will give the proposed answers.

Comment: Furthermore, -6 is an answer as well, $\frac{1}{\log_2(-6-2)^2}+\frac{1}{\log_2(-6+2)^2} = \frac{1}{\log_2(-8)^2}+\frac{1}{\log_2(-4)^2} = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{12}$